# IBM WebSphere commerce: Manually create, edit and delete Attributes

Tags: websphere-commerce

I'm maintaining an API to manage several IBM commerce data systems.

What I need is to create, edit or remove attributes, their values and their descriptions. Basically, I need to work using the `ATTR`, `ATTR_DESC`, `ATTRVAL` and `ATTRVAL_DESC` tables.

I thought there was an `AttributeCreateCmd`, but I couldn't find it. What I found was the `AttributeValueAddCmd` command, but it seems that it is not working (maybe I'm not using it correctly). I need to handle the attributes
among the attribute values.

I tried also with `AttributeBean` and `AttributeDataBean`, but it seems that that's not the stuff I need.

What I know is the model objects that I need to work with are `Attr` and `AttrVal`, but I don't know what `*Cmd`, `*Bean` or whatever I need to maintain that data.

Is there something that does exactly what I need?

Comment: what is your question? it's not clear what you are trying to do or what you are having trouble with

Comment: Hi aguibert, thank you for your answer. I need to manage the Webpshere attribute data, https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.database.doc/database/attr.htm. I need to create, edit or remove entries in that ATTR table (well.. also in the ATTR_VAL table too).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to manage the ATTR data manually, seems you have to use AttributeDictionaryMediator, but I was unable to use it.

Finally I implemented the commands to access the tables, to use them wherever I need them.